# Why is blender not rendering my object to scale?

Tags: rendering, armature, scale

When I render my object, it is not producing the object at the same scale as in the camera viewport.
I imported this object as FBX and scaled it up in the viewport. I then applied scale to be safe. When I render the object, it comes out very small. I've also tried rendering other objects in this same file and they work fine, so it is something related to the object itself. The object also has an armature. Could this affect the scale?

[image: As seen in the screenshot, the viewport is set to camera view and the render previews shows a tiny version of the item.]

Comment: Do you have any modifiers or constraints on the object or its armature? It's possible one or more of these are enabled for renders but not the viewport.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out. This happened because the armature was animated and the render must have been rendering a different frame. Since I don't need the animation, I right clicked on the armature and removed the "Animation" entries. This solved the problem.